# Make a sub directory public on .Net core webAPI

Tags: rest, .net-core, web-config, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a Restful API project with .Net Core 1 that has a directory that contains some public files (ex: images). I created a controller that retrieved files by file name, but I think it uses CPU and it had has much delay.

for example:

```
wwwroot
- refs
- runtimes
+ public
    - logo.png
    + subdir
        - icon1.png
        - icon2.png
```

I want to access this directory publicly from a url like this

```
https://MyAPIDomain.com/public/logo.png
https://MyAPIDomain.com/public/subdir/icon1.png
```

I want to IIS directly handles these files and no need to process with dot net. Also they should be resumable on download and browsers could be able to cache theme. How can I do that?

**web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: My first question would be why you would want to host [static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) inside a REST API...

Comment: @rickvdbosch they are not exactly static. They are some uploaded files that I need be public. The above is just an example.

Comment: Those are called static files ;) Have a look at the link I put in there. Might help you

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core uses IIS as a reverse-proxy. What this means is that *all* requests are forwarded to your ASP.NET Core app. Period. There's no way around that. The only way you can get IIS to directly serve a file is to host it in a virtual directory in your IIS site. Then, because that particular path is now handled by IIS, it will not forward to your ASP.NET Core app. However, that means then that your ASP.NET Core app can no longer work with that path. In other words, you can't create a virtual directory like "public" and also serve files separately under `wwwroot/public`.

That said, the static files middleware runs relatively early in the pipeline and is also pretty lightweight. I honestly doubt you'd see much, if any, performance decline over directly hosting static files in IIS. It's also much easier with the static files middleware to handle things like setting cache headers. I'd suggest you simply leave things as they are.

Comment: So can I set one of existing directories in the project as a virtual directory, then, when writing use real name and when reading use virtual name?